# How to refer to a property provided in command line through its number?

Tags: properties, jmeter

I want to know how to refer to a specific property provided in command line. E.g. property number 1, number 2, number 3. Without  using the name of the property.

Obviously I use the `__Property` function to refer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access [`JMeterUtils.getJMeterProperties()`](http://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/util/JMeterUtils.html#getJMeterProperties%28%29) in Beanshell. It will return java.util.Properties and then you can use it.

You can't do it through `__Property` function